# 32Feet list / remove / put file on a bluetooth digital photo frame

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I can authenticate myself on the device with this code:

```
var dev = new BluetoothDeviceInfo(BluetoothAddress.Parse("0015836A3C0A"));
if (!dev.Authenticated)
    BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(dev.DeviceAddress, "0000");
```

But now, I would like put / remove / list files on the device.

I'm tying with ObexWebRequest but I have Connect Fails error.

I can't find a complete example to perform these actions.

Could you help me?

Thank you